# php отображает исходный код, а не заданный текст

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой, что локальный сервер отображает полностью код, а не то чтобы я хотел видеть. Мне нужно чтобы отображалось просто "Hello, PHP"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот полный код
Переписал его из книги Алексея Васильева руками.
Суть проблемы в том, что мне выводит исходный код, а мне нужно чтобы выводило только содержимое скобок

Comment: А почему вы решили, что ваш локальный сервер в принципе должен выполнять php-код? Вы его как-нибудь настраивали для этого?

Comment: первое - покажи весь код.... второе - ты сервер-то включил?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Более подробно описал ситуацию

Comment: На каком серваке запускаешь? Какие настройки сервака для проекта? Почему на скрине нет открывающего тега?

Comment: Обычный локальный сервер, в книге по поводу настроек ничего не говорится, скорее всего из-за этого и проблемы

Comment: Что такое "обычный локальный сервер"? У серверов обычно конкретные названия есть

Comment: хорошая ссылка на мануал по установке Openserver https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-openserver

Comment: Что по поводу открывающего тега? И на счёт того, что написал andreymal?

Comment: Хочу добавить, что это не только на серваке, но и в редакторе кода

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы пхп отображал результат выполнения скрипта, а не сам скрипт, нужно правильно настроить сервер, самым простым сервером для винды является openserver, не требующий каких-либо настроек, иные варианты несколько сложнее. О вашем сервере могу только гадать,- в частности он почемуто открыт на порте тсп 6467, а не на стандартных портах 8000, 8080, вероятно вы неверно настроили сервер и к пхп проблема имеет лишь косвенное решение.

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас буду пробовать